# How to test polymorphic controllers in Rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, polymorphic-associations

Dear fellow Overflowers,

I will try to give the essence of my issue. Thanks in advance for your patience.

My Polymorphic Controller (`Appointments`) is accessed by two `Views`, the first belongs to `Admin::Doctor` namespace and the second one to `Patient` namespace.

the relevant part of the `routes.rb`:

```
map.resources :patient do |patients|
  patients.resources :appointments
end

map.namespace(:admin) do |admin|
  admin.resources :doctor do |doctors|
    doctors.resources :appointments
  end
end
```

So, I can now get:

```
patients/:patient_id/appointments
admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments
```

...and the actual routes:

`rake routes | grep appointment`

```
 new_patient_appointments GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/new(.:format)    {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"new"}
edit_patient_appointments GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/edit(.:format)  {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"edit"}
     patient_appointments GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments(.:format)            {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"show"}
                          PUT    /patients/:patient_id/appointments(.:format)            {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"update"}
                          DELETE /patients/:patient_id/appointments(.:format)   {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"destroy"}
                          POST   /patients/:patient_id/appointments(.:format)   {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"create"}

 new_admin_doctor_appointments GET    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments/new(.:format) {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"new"}
edit_admin_doctor_appointments GET    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments/edit(.:format){:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"edit"}
     admin_doctor_appointments GET    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)     {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"show"}
                               PUT    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)    {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"update"}
                               DELETE /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)   {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"destroy"}
                               POST   /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)   {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"create"}
```

My models:

```
class Patient
  has_many :appointments, :as => :attendee
end

class Doctor
  has_many :appointments, :as => :attendee
end

class Appointment
  belongs_to :attendee, :polymorphic => true
end
```

My controllers:

`Controllers/Admin/doctors_controller.rb`

```
class Admin::DoctorsController < AuthorisedController
end
```

`Controllers/appointments_controller.rb`

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
end
```

`Controllers/patients_controller.rb`

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
end
```

On my `test/functional/appointments_controller_test.rb`, I am testing for `patients` without errors but when testing for `doctors`, I get an `ActionController::RoutingError`:

```
4) Error:
test_should_show_doctor_appointment(AppointmentsControllerTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"appointments", :id=>"281110143", :action=>"show", :doctor_id=>2}
test/functional/appointments_controller_test.rb:55:in `test_should_show_doctor_appointment'
```

EDIT:

The relevant part in the tests:

`test/functional/appointments_controller_test.rb`

```
require 'test_helper'

class AppointmentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  fixtures :patients, :appointments, :doctors, :users
  # The following passes:

  def setup
    login_as :admin
  end

  test "should show patient appointment" do
    get :show, :id => patients(:one).to_param, :appointment_id => appointments(:app_one).id
    assert_response :success
  end

  # The following fails, giving the error mentioned above:

  test "should show doctor appointment" do
    get :show, :id => doctors(:one).to_param, :appointment_id => appointments(:app_one).id
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

As @Ryan pointed out, the test is under the base namespace, so as a next step, I created a test under `Admin`.

`test/functional/admin/appointments_controller_test.rb`

```
class Admin::AppointmentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  fixtures :patients, :appointments, :doctors, :users
  # The following passes:

  def setup
    login_as :admin
  end

  test "should show doctor appointment" do
    get :show, :id => doctors(:one).to_param, :appointment_id => appointments(:app_one).id
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

...and now I get this error:

```
 1) Error:
 test_should_show_doctor_appointment(Admin::AppointmentsControllerTest):
 RuntimeError: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
 test/functional/admin/appointments_controller_test.rb:13:in `test_should_show_doctor_appointment'
```

At this point, I added `@controller = AppointmentsController.new` under the `setup` method, only to get the very familiar:

```
1) Error:
test_should_show_doctor_appointments(Admin::AppointmentsControllerTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"appointments", :doctor_id=>2, :id=>"281110143"}
test/functional/admin/appointments_controller_test.rb:14:in `test_should_show_doctor_appointments'
```

It seems to me like a vicious circle.

EDIT END

So, since the test can not find the controller because its route points at `admin/appointments`

- why am I able to render `/admin/doctors/1/appointments` since the `appointments_controller.rb` does not live neither under `Admin` folder nor `Admin::` namespace (but the route points there) and
- what is the best strategy to write the functional tests for that case?

Thank you in advance!

pR

Comment: run the command `gem install rails -v 4.0.0` and then try again. =D

Comment: So, does Rails 4.0.0 solve the problem?

Comment: Well, I don't know much about polymorphic controllers in rails 2.3.18 to help and unfortunately, with that rails version, some of the younger programmers like myself weren't even programming when it was current. It is hard trying to find support for older versions like that, and if you can upgrade I would recommend it.

Comment: Well, not so hard in any case: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/

Answer (score 1):

This error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"appointments", :id=>"281110143", :action=>"show", :doctor_id=>2}
```

Shows that you're making a request to a controller called `AppointmentsController`, but judging by your routes:

```
new_admin_doctor_appointments GET    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments/new(.:format) {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"new"}
edit_admin_doctor_appointments GET    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments/edit(.:format){:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"edit"}
     admin_doctor_appointments GET    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)     {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"show"}
                               PUT    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)    {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"update"}
                               DELETE /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)   {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"destroy"}
                               POST   /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)   {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"create"}
```

That route is only available within the admin namespace, i.e. `Admin::AppointmentsController`.

I'm going to bet that you're doing something like `describe AppointmentsController` rather than `describe Admin::AppointmentsController`. I don't know for certain because you've not included the critical part that is the test itself.

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for taking the time! You were right on the namespace scope and have gone one step further but I am still getting errors. I have added the relevant parts.

Comment: @Cacofonix: Please open a new question for this new problem rather than modifying the existing question.

Comment: This has been done at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208722/how-to-test-controllers-under-different-namespaces-and-why-this-test-fails