# How to test Controllers under different namespaces and why this test fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, polymorphic-associations

Dear fellow Overflowers,

I am using Rails 2.3 and I have created a polymorphic Controller which is accessed by Views belonging to different namespaces. Here is the story and thanks for reading it in advance:

I have these routes:

`rake routes | grep appointment`

```
 new_patient_appointments GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/new(.:format)    {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"new"}
edit_patient_appointments GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments/edit(.:format)  {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"edit"}
     patient_appointments GET    /patients/:patient_id/appointments(.:format)            {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"show"}
                          PUT    /patients/:patient_id/appointments(.:format)            {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"update"}
                          DELETE /patients/:patient_id/appointments(.:format)   {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"destroy"}
                          POST   /patients/:patient_id/appointments(.:format)   {:controller=>"appointments", :action=>"create"}

 new_admin_doctor_appointments GET    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments/new(.:format) {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"new"}
edit_admin_doctor_appointments GET    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments/edit(.:format){:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"edit"}
     admin_doctor_appointments GET    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)     {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"show"}
                               PUT    /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)    {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"update"}
                               DELETE /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)   {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"destroy"}
                               POST   /admin/doctors/:doctor_id/appointments(.:format)   {:controller=>"admin/appointments", :action=>"create"}
```

...these controllers:

`Controllers/Admin/doctors_controller.rb`

```
class Admin::DoctorsController < AuthorisedController
end
```

`Controllers/appointments_controller.rb`

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
end
```

`Controllers/patients_controller.rb`

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
end
```

...and these tests:

The relevant part in the tests:

`test/functional/appointments_conrtroller_test.rb`

```
require 'test_helper'

class AppointmentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  fixtures :patients, :appointments, :doctors, :users
  # The following passes:

  def setup
    login_as :admin
  end

  test "should show patient appointment" do
    get :show, :id => patients(:one).to_param, :appointment_id => appointments(:app_one).id
    assert_response :success
  end

  # The following fails, giving the error after the code block:

  test "should show doctor appointment" do
    get :show, :id => doctors(:one).to_param, :appointment_id => appointments(:app_one).id
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

Error:

```
4) Error:
test_should_show_doctor_appointment(AppointmentsControllerTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"appointments", :id=>"281110143", :action=>"show", :doctor_id=>2}
test/functional/appointments_controller_test.rb:55:in `test_should_show_doctor_appointment'
```

the test is under the base namespace, so as a next step, I created a test under `Admin`.

`test/functional/admin/appointments_controller_test.rb`

```
class Admin::AppointmentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  fixtures :patients, :appointments, :doctors, :users
  # The following passes:

  def setup
    login_as :admin
  end

  test "should show doctor appointment" do
    get :show, :id => doctors(:one).to_param, :appointment_id => appointments(:app_one).id
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

...and now I get this error:

```
 1) Error:
 test_should_show_doctor_appointment(Admin::AppointmentsControllerTest):
 RuntimeError: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
 test/functional/admin/appointments_controller_test.rb:13:in `test_should_show_doctor_appointment'
```

At this point, I added `@controller = AppointmentsController.new` under the `setup` method, only to get the very familiar:

```
1) Error:
test_should_show_doctor_appointments(Admin::AppointmentsControllerTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"appointments", :doctor_id=>2, :id=>"281110143"}
test/functional/admin/appointments_controller_test.rb:14:in `test_should_show_doctor_appointments'
```

It seems like a vicious circle to me.

Thanks anyways...

pR

Answer (score 4):

You should probably be doing this instead:

```
@controller = Admin::AppointmentsController.new
```

Otherwise you're referencing the controller inside the main namespace and not the `Admin` namespace.

Comment: That is correct; however, I now get this error:

    1) Error:
    test_should_show_doctor_appointments(Admin::AppointmentsControllerTest):
    NameError: uninitialized constant Admin::AppointmentsController
        test/functional/admin/appointments_controller_test.rb:12:in `setup'

Comment: Well that problem is pretty indicative of the next step... it's clear to me that you don't have an `Admin::AppointmentsController`, but yet you're attempting to route to one. Create one using `rails g controller admin/appointments`.

Comment: Hey Ryan, that is true but was pretty indicative from the question though. My question is (also mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190071/how-to-test-polymorphic-controllers-in-rails-2-3)), why then my ```View``` is rendered even when I have no ```Admin::AppointmentsController```? I am looking for a solution that will just not throw the Polymorphic controller out of the window...

Thanks anyways...